# Could not send Message : SocketTimeoutException : NotAuthorizedException

Tags: java, jetty, cxf, jax-rs

I'm using Jetty and getting the following problem on my build server (I don't get it on my dev machine).

```
2013-07-22 14:19:20,647972350: WARN  : org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain: Interceptor for {http://rs.rtiservice.esi.v21.xxxx.com/}RTIServiceRSI has thrown exception, unwinding now
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Could not send Message.
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:64)
<SNIP>
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: SocketTimeoutException invoking http://localhost:25000/esi-rtiservice/ESI/RTIService/rs-rtiservice/addLineItem/: Read timed out
<SNIP>
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:62)
    ... 104 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
<SNIP>
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1308)
    ... 107 more
2013-07-22 14:19:20,654681221: ERROR : [qtp23135205-124] com.xxx.v21.mpos.MPOSEndPoint: System error
javax.ws.rs.NotAuthorizedException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
<SNIP>
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
2013-07-22 14:19:20,656234277: WARN  :  org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain: Interceptor for {http://mpos.v21.xxx.com/}MPOSEndPoint has thrown exception, unwinding now
java.lang.IllegalStateException: WRITER
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Response.getOutputStream(Response.java:673)
<SNIP>
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
2013-07-22 14:19:20,658931461: WARN  : [qtp23135205-124] org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain: Interceptor for {http://mpos.v21.xxx.com/}MPOSEndPoint has thrown exception, unwinding now
java.lang.IllegalStateException: WRITER
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Response.getOutputStream(Response.java:673)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.flushHeaders(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:564)
```

Now I can see that some people say I need to set `ReceiveTimeout` on my connection.[1](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/server-http-transport.html)
These people don't seem to have an `NotAuthorizedException` like I do.

All the examples I see are like this:

```
<http-conf:destination 
     name="{http://apache.org/hello_world_soap_http}SoapPort.http-destination">
    <http-conf:server ReceiveTimeout="30000"
                      HonorKeepAlive="true" />
  </http-conf:destination>
```

Conversely, I've defined mine like this:

```
<jaxrs:client id="itemService" address="http://${itemservice.address}/esi-itemservice/ESI/ItemService" serviceClass="com.xxx.v21.esi.itemservice.rs.ItemServiceRSI" inheritHeaders="true">
        <jaxrs:headers>
            <entry key="Accept" value="application/xml" />
        </jaxrs:headers>
        <jaxrs:providers>
            <ref bean="jaxbextprovider" />
        </jaxrs:providers>
    </jaxrs:client>
```

Can someone tell me how to set the `ReceiveTimeout` on my connection - Or give me something else to go on please?

Comment: The WebService is secured. You need the credentials.

Comment: The NotAuthorizedException is the *result* of the prior timeout. It is he timeout you have to solve here, not its result.

Answer (score -1):

I've not found the reason for this, but the work around that I've taken is to switch from Jetty in my integration tests and to start using Cargo to download Tomcat, install the artifact/wars and run the tests.

Cargo is taking 5 seconds a test, Jetty was taking 5 minutes!! So they now all run and it takes 2 minutes to run, not almost an hour!

In short, have a look at Cargo (cargo.codehaus.org)

```
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
        <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.5</version>
        <configuration>
          <container>
            <containerId>tomcat7x</containerId>
            <zipUrlInstaller>
              <url>ftp://x.x.x.x/install_pack/Tomcat7/tomcat7.zip</url>
              <downloadDir>${project.build.directory}/cargo/downloads</downloadDir>
            </zipUrlInstaller>
            <output>${project.build.directory}/cargo/container.log</output>
            <append>false</append>
            <log>${project.build.directory}/cargo/cargo.log</log>
            <timeout>240000</timeout>
            <systemProperties>
              <logLevel>INFO</logLevel>
              <itemservice.address>localhost:9080</itemservice.address>
              <deviceservice.address>localhost:9080</deviceservice.address>
              <userservice.address>localhost:9080</userservice.address>
              <rtiservice.address>localhost:9080</rtiservice.address>
              <corporateservice.address>localhost:9080</corporateservice.address>
            </systemProperties>
          </container>
          <configuration>
            <properties>
              <cargo.servlet.port>9080</cargo.servlet.port>
              <cargo.tomcat.ajp.port>9085</cargo.tomcat.ajp.port>
              <cargo.jvmargs>-XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled</cargo.jvmargs>
              <cargo.logging>high</cargo.logging>
            </properties>
          </configuration>
          <deployables>
            <deployable>
              <groupId>com.test</groupId>
              <artifactId>test-war</artifactId>
              <type>war</type>
            </deployable>
          </deployables>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>start-server</id>
            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>start</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>stop-server</id>
            <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>stop</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
```

Comment: Hard to see how this provides an answer that is actually useful.

Comment: Since no one has come up with an answer to this, I thought it would be good to put down the work around I've come to. Incase someone else has the same problem.